# in multple regression, what does that mean when estimation of intercept is the same as variable estimate

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

```
Call:
lm(formula = y_diff ~ gender_composition_two + con_diff + gender_composition_two:con_diff, 
    data = dat3)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.7619 -0.0002  0.0000  0.0000  8.1198 

Coefficients:
                                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                              2.11879    0.07702  27.508  < 2e-16 ***
gender_composition_twosame-sex          -2.11879    0.11113 -19.065  < 2e-16 ***
con_diff                                -0.40425    0.05271  -7.669 9.22e-14 ***
gender_composition_twosame-sex:con_diff  2.40425    0.09657  24.897  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.091 on 496 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6235,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6212 
F-statistic: 273.8 on 3 and 496 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

as you can see, the estimate of intercept is 2.11879
and one categorical variable (gender_composition_twi) has also the same value, with a different value. (this is a dummy coded binary variable)

What is happening?

This is simulated data without error variance
if you want to see the data, see the below

````
con_vcovmatrix=matrix(c(1,0,0,0,
                                            0,1,0,1,
                                            0,0,1,0,
                                            0,1,0,1),
                                          nrow = 4,
                                          byrow = TRUE,
                                          dimnames = list(c("con_wtn_1","con_btw_1","con_wtn_2","con_btw_2"),
                                                          c("con_wtn_1","con_btw_1","con_wtn_2","con_btw_2")))

 con_mu=c(0,0,0,0)
 dat <- MASS::mvrnorm(500, # cluster  number
                       mu = con_mu, # Mu
                       Sigma = con_vcovmatrix)%>% # Covariance matrix
    as.data.frame() 
 
 dat<-dat %>%
    mutate(
      pid = 1:500,
      con_1 = con_wtn_1 +  con_btw_1,
      con_2 =  con_wtn_2 + con_btw_2,
     
      catwtn_1 = sample(rep(c(-1, 1), 250)),
      catwtn_2 = sample(rep(c(-1, 1), 250)),
     
      catbtw_1 = case_when(
        catwtn_1 == 1 & catwtn_2 == 1 ~ 1,
        catwtn_1 == 1 & catwtn_2 == -1 ~ -1,
        catwtn_1 == -1 & catwtn_2 == 1 ~ -1,
        catwtn_1 == -1 & catwtn_2 == -1 ~ 1,
      ),
      catbtw_2 = catbtw_1,

      cat_1 =  catbtw_1 +  catwtn_1,
      cat_2 =  catbtw_2 +  catwtn_2,

      y_1 = con_1 * cat_1,
      y_2 = con_2 * cat_2) 
 
 dat<-dat %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric))
 
 data<-dat
 
 
  data <- data %>%
    dplyr::mutate(higher_one = case_when(
      y_1>y_2~"1",
      y_1<y_2~"2",
      y_1==y_2~"equal")
    )

  ## subset

  # randomly assign tie siblings
  p <- stats::rbinom(1,1,0.5)

  data[data$higher_one=="equal",]<-ifelse(p==0,"1","2")

  # splice the data

  dat1<-data[data$higher_one=="1",]
  dat2<-data[data$higher_one=="2",]

  # change the column names
  dat2 <- dat2 %>%
    dplyr::mutate(y_2_1=y_2,
                  y_1_2=y_1,
                  con_1_2=con_1,
                  con_2_1=con_2,
                  cat_1_2=cat_1,
                  cat_2_1=cat_2,
                  catwtn_1_2=catwtn_1,
                  catwtn_2_1=catwtn_2
    ) %>%
    subset(
      select=-c(y_1,
                y_2,
                con_1,
                con_2,
                cat_1,
                cat_2,
                catwtn_1,
                catwtn_2
      )
    ) %>%
    dplyr::rename(y_1=y_2_1,
                  y_2=y_1_2,
                  con_2=con_1_2,
                  con_1=con_2_1,
                  cat_2=cat_1_2,
                  cat_1=cat_2_1,
                  catwtn_1=catwtn_2_1,
                  catwtn_2=catwtn_1_2)

  dat3<-rbind(dat1,dat2)

  
 dat3<-dat3%>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric))
  # calculate mean score and difference score

  dat3<-dat3 %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      con_mean = (con_1+con_2)/2,
      con_diff = con_1-con_2,
      y_mean = (y_1+y_2)/2,
      y_diff = y_1-y_2
    )

  dat3$higher_one <- NULL

  dat3<-dat3 %>%
    mutate(
      gender_composition_two=case_when(
        catwtn_1==catwtn_2 ~ "same-sex",
        catwtn_1!=catwtn_2 ~ "mixed-sex"),

      gender_composition_three=case_when(
        catwtn_1==1 & catwtn_2==1 ~ "oneone",
        catwtn_1==-1 & catwtn_2==-1 ~ "mimi",
        catwtn_1!=catwtn_2 ~ "mixed"),

      gender_composition_two_eff=case_when(
        catwtn_1==catwtn_2 ~ 1,
        catwtn_1!=catwtn_2 ~ -1),
      # three levels : need two coding variable.
      ev1 = case_when(catwtn_1==catwtn_2 & catwtn_1==1 ~ 1,
                      catwtn_1==catwtn_2 & catwtn_1==-1 ~ 0,
                      catwtn_1!=catwtn_2 ~ -1), # reference
      ev2 = case_when(catwtn_1==catwtn_2 & catwtn_1==1 ~ 0,
                      catwtn_1==catwtn_2 & catwtn_1==-1 ~ 1,
                      catwtn_1!=catwtn_2 ~ -1) # reference
    )

```
````

Comment: could you show the head of the data?

Comment: @Amin Shn   I uploded the data generating codes:)

Comment: The results mean that the mean value for the same-sex group is ZERO when the value of "con_diff" is zero. In other words, the intercept within the same_sex group is zero.